# Why are my RGB values slightly off when trying to implement a box blur on a image for PSET4 in CS50?

Tags: c, blur, cs50

I've worked on this for a couple weeks to no avail. I think the logic and implementation is sound, yet it fails all of the tests except blurring the corner pixels.

**My logic: copy every pixel from the original infile image to an identical one, calculate the average of  RGB values in each neighboring pixel (if exists), then apply back to the original image**. My implementation scans each pixel's above row, row, and below row via nested loops. I know this isn't the most succinct way to implement -- I'm new to this.

Here is an example of one such error:

> :( blur incorrectly filters 3x3 image
>
> Expected Output
>
> 70 85 95
>
> 80 95 105
>
> 90 105 115
>
> 117 130 140
>
> 127 140 149
>
> 137 150 159
>
> 163 178 188
>
> 170 185 194
>
> 178 193 201

My results:

> Actual Output
>
> 70 85 95
>
> 90 106 116
>
> 103 119 129
>
> 135 150 160
>
> 145 160 169
>
> 155 169 178
>
> 175 188 197
>
> 178 191 200
>
> 180 193 201

Here is my code (written in C):

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE imageCopy[height][width];
                                            //assign new image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            imageCopy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int red = 0;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;
            float pixelCount = 0.00;
                                                        //scan top row
            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
            {
                if ((i - 1) >= 0 && (j + k) >= 0 && (j + k) < width)
                {
                    red += imageCopy[i - 1][j + k].rgbtRed;
                    green += imageCopy[i - 1][j + k].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += imageCopy[i - 1][j + k].rgbtBlue;
                    pixelCount++;
                }
            }
                                                        //scan same row
            for (int m = -1; m < 2; m++)
            {
                if ((j + m) >= 0 && (j + m) < width)
                {
                    red += imageCopy[i][j + m].rgbtRed;
                    green += imageCopy[i][j + m].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += imageCopy[i][j + m].rgbtBlue;
                    pixelCount++;
                }
            }
                                                        //scan below row
            for (int n = -1; n < 2; n++)
            {
                if ((i + 1) < height && (j + n) >= 0 && (j + n) < width)
                {
                    red += imageCopy[i + 1][j + n].rgbtRed;
                    green += imageCopy[i + 1][j + n].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += imageCopy[i + 1][j + n].rgbtBlue;
                    pixelCount++;
                }
            }
                                                        // find averages
            imageCopy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / pixelCount);
            imageCopy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / pixelCount);
            imageCopy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / pixelCount);
        }
    }
                                                        // assign back to original image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = imageCopy[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 4 corners + 4 edges in a pixel matrix + ones in the middle. So you have to take into account 9 different cases, but i only see 3 cases in your logic.

Comment: @earik87 Right, but shouldn't my algo handle that? If the scanning exceeds the width or height, it doesn't count that "pixel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the **problem**.

You calculate for every pixel a new "blurred" value, and the logic out there seems to be fine. What you do at the end, is to assign pixels to their "new blurred value" with this piece of code.

```
imageCopy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / pixelCount);
imageCopy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / pixelCount);
imageCopy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / pixelCount);
```

This is not okay, because you apply "blur" filtering to the image that has been already changed. So what you do is actually you change one pixel with a blurred one, then for the neighbourhood pixel you use the "blurred" pixel next to it for calculation which is wrong.

**Solution;**

`imageCopy` should not be changed during calculation, because all the blur calculation should be done on "original image". At the end of each pixel, you should pass values directly to `image`. Replace `imageCopy` with `image`, like below.

```
image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / pixelCount);
image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / pixelCount);
image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / pixelCount);
```

And remove this for loop from the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = imageCopy[i][j];
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, that makes so much sense. Can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks for the help!